# word (in square brackets) definition in haskell

Tags: haskell

Dear retrospective Programmers,

Within my Haskell-Code i had to define a function with the Definition [Word] -> [Word]

my first question in this website is very simple. What does the [Word] type variable mean in Haskell? I.e what does it represent?

GDash69

Comment: Not sure what @machavity wants wrt clarity, it seems clear @GDash69. Welcome to the Haskell SO community.  The short answer (due to comment) is this is not a "type variable" but a "type".  `[Word]` is a list of `Word`s. A Word is an unsigned bounded integer.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets `[ ]` indicate a list. For example, the type for a list of Int values is `[Int]`, the type for a list of any one type inside is `[a]`.

Your list is a type called a `Word`, so the list of word is with the square brackets and looks like `[ Word ]`.  A Word is a bounded unsigned integer. This means you can store values 0, 1, 2, all the way up to some maximum. The Haskell language specification only guarantees these to be at least 29 bits but the compilers you see in real life are all working on machine word sizes (32 bits or 64 bits).  If Haskell borrowed from C terms then it might have called this `[ UInt ]`.

> i had to define a function with the Definition [Word] -> [Word]

An aside on terms: This is a function type signature. A definition would be the expression, code that gets executed when you call the function.

Comment: That's assuming the OP's `Word` refers to [`Prelude.Word`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Word) (aka `Data.Word.Word`). It could plausibly refer to some custom type like `newtype Word = Word {getStringWithoutSpaces :: String}` instead, though that would mean the standard definition would need to be hidden.

Comment: Absolutely right @leftaroundabout. I assumed we're talking about a vanilla environment with `Prelude` as the import of interest.